# CrossBrowser Support for window.close()

Tags: javascript, html, datepicker, internet-explorer-11

I have a date picker javascript, where in window.close() was not working for IE11,chrome39 and ff 34. I have used the below code instead which works fine in chrome and firefox but not in IE11. Can anyone please let me know an alternative as how to fix it in IE11?

```
window.open('','_parent','');window.close();
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: which `datepicker` you are using? and why you need `window.close`?

Comment: I am using javascript date-picker

Comment: Please the link. It would be great if you create a fiddle for it.

Answer (score 0):

**[Untested]** You can use it like:

```
var win= window.open('','_parent','');
    win.close();
```

or

```
var win= window.open('','_self','');
    win.close();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
window.open('','_self');
window.close();
```

Although, I would not suggest this. It's a hack-ish way of doing things and hack-ish ways are never 100% cross-browser safe.

Happy coding

Answer (score 0):

Using the close() function alone might work. In your case try this:

```
window.open('','_parent',''); closeWindow();

function closeWindow() {
  close();
}
```

You can also use it this way:

```
window.open('','_parent','').Function(closeWindow()); //close after the new window has been opened

function closeWindow() {
   close();
}
```